# Problems with a character counting program in C on online compilers

Tags: c

I'm a newcomer to programming so please forgive me for my stupid questions. I ran the following code on [repl.it](https://repl.it/) and [JDoodle](https://www.jdoodle.com/c-online-compiler) respectively.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{   
    int nc;
    nc = 0;
    while(getchar() != EOF)
        nc = nc + 1;
    printf("%d\n", nc);
}
```

On [JDoodle](https://www.jdoodle.com/c-online-compiler), the results are always x+1 where x is the number I expected. For example, if I input `123123`, the result is 7. Besides, if I leave the input empty, [JDoodle](https://www.jdoodle.com/c-online-compiler) tells me that `Your Program may have a endless loop`. Why these happen?

On [repl.it](https://repl.it/), after I type the input on the right side of the screen and press Enter, there is no response. However the input copying program

```
int c;
c = getchar();
while(c != EOF){
    putchar(c);
    c = getchar();
}
```

works well on [repl.it](https://repl.it/). Why the character counting program cannot work on [repl.it](https://repl.it/)? I will appreciate any help with these situations.

Comment: Hint: Did input `123123` include an <enter> key?

Comment: Dear @chux: No Enter key. I just input `123123` in "Stdin Inputs..." and pressed the "Execute" button.

Comment: The difference could be that one system terminates lines with just newline while the other terminates lines with CRLF (carriage return, line feed), which means that if there's one line of input, there might be a difference of one in the counts.  Sometimes the systems will map CRLF to just newline (and LF is also known as newline); sometimes they may not.  It depends on the underlying O/S, and on whether the standard input is treated as text or binary data.  You could try printing each character as it is read: `int c; while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) { printf("[%d]", c); nc++; } putchar('\n');`.

Comment: @lightweight, it appears the **Execute** button is hiding something from you. When you press **Execute**, the input will be passed to your program as `"123123\n"` where `'\n'` being the POSIX line-end let's whatever know that it has received a line of input. So the comment about the **<enter>** key should be telling you that input required for the *remote* execution of your code on some machine over the internet is no different than it would be if you were compiling and running locally (which if you plan on learning to program, is something I would strongly suggest you do...)

Comment: this line: `while(getchar() != EOF)`  One of the characters that will be input is '\n' (the newline) that you entered when you clicked the 'enter' key.  TO get a good count, suggest: `int ch;  while( (ch = getchar()) != EOF && '\n' != ch )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following proposed code:

1. corrects the problem discussed in the comments to the question.

The differences between the two web pages is of no consequence to the problem seen by the OP.

And now the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    int nc = 0;
    int ch;  // the character input from stdin

    while( (ch = getchar()) != EOF && '\n' != ch)
        nc = nc + 1;

    printf("%d\n", nc);
}
```